# Using Google OR-Tools for a goal seeker in C#?

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization, or-tools

I am trying to code a multi variable goal seeker in C#. The main idea is having a set of variables x_1 to x_n, which can be altered by the solver, so the objective function f(x) comes as close as possible to a given value Z.

So far I've mainly used the GLOP_LinearSolver, which only is able to minimize or maximize the objective function. To work around that, I've wanted to minimize the absolute square of f(x)-Z, but the GLOP_LinearSolver does not include an absolute value or a square operator (from my understanding none of the OR-Tools solvers do).

My question is: Is it possible to realise this goal seeker with Google OR-Tools?
If yes: What would be a workaround for my problem?
If no: What other package could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective function

```
 min |f(x) - Z|
```

can be reformulated as:

```
 min d1 + d2
     f(x) + d1 - d2 = Z
     d1, d2 ≥ 0
```

As long as `f(x)` is linear, this can be fed into any LP solver.

d1 and d2 are positive and negative deviations or slacks. We minimize the deviations, so we end up with f(x) as close to Z as possible. Note that in the optimal solution, only one of d1,d2 can be non-zero (not both). E.g. if f(x)=10 and Z=8 then d1=0,d2=2. If f(x)=7 and Z=8 then d1=1,d2=0.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a bit more? I sadly don't quite follow.

Comment: I added some notes. This is a very standard formulation and should be rather obvious.

Comment: Does [this](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/absolute.htm) explain in more detail what you mean? Could you also give me a name for that reformulation or point me in some direction? Since I did not study math and the math I had in my studies was not on english, I feel like I lack the vocabulary to just google it. Thanks for the effort though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: It is related. But I think it is a bit easier to interpret d1,d2 directly as positive and negative deviations. Not much math going on here, just arithmetic. In any case, even if you don't understand it immediately, you can use it right away. Just implement (i.e. transcribe) it in code. Looking at some solutions may help.